# Error While Creating Custom Authentication for 2GP Managed Package

Tags: oauth-2.0, apex, lwc

I have an LWC that retrieves field dependencies in the salesforce org and I have used a connected app, auth provider, and named credential in the component I want to pack the component using 2GP managed package and since 2GP does not support auth provider I need to create a custom authentication for the LWC.

I have created a custom authentication using an apex class and used git hub for client id and consumer secret and I am getting the below error USER_DEBUG [105]|DEBUG|An error occurred in the getUserInfo method: Attempt to de-reference a null object I have whitelisted the URL and provided the callback URL.